# How to clear Microsoft Edge browser cache programmatically?

Tags: c#, browser-cache, microsoft-edge

Does anyone know how to clear the cache of Microsoft Edge programmatically? (either .Net, script, command line, deleting files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\
```

And delete folders that start with `#!`.

Comment: From a command line: rmdir %LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\ /s /q

Comment: This no longer seems to work. Edge is always running. Even if I end the task, it still holds the folders open/active.

Answer (score 7):

The location given above I think is wrong. Below is the location for cookies, history and Cache.

directory: C:\Users%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Cache

file: C:\Users%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Cookies

file: C:\Users%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\History

Answer (score 0):

**in python you can do the following**

```
def _edgeClearTemp():

    appdata_location = os.environ.get('LOCALAPPDATA')
    _edgeTempDir = r"{0}\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC".format(
        appdata_location)
    _edgeAppData = r"{0}\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppData".format(
        appdata_location)

    try:
        os.system("taskkill  /F /IM MicrosoftEdge.exe")
    except:
        pass
    try:
        os.system("taskkill  /F /IM dllhost.exe")
    except:
        pass
    if os.path.exists(_edgeTempDir):
        for directory in os.listdir(_edgeTempDir):
            if directory.startswith('#!'):
                shutil.rmtree(
                    os.path.join(_edgeTempDir, directory), ignore_errors=True)

    if os.path.exists(_edgeAppData):
        shutil.rmtree(_edgeAppData, ignore_errors=True)
```

[python](/questions/tagged/python) [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) [edge](/questions/tagged/edge)