# Is there any way to clear the cache, cookies & History for Edge Browser

Tags: c#, .net, rpa, uipath

I am working on RPA Automations Project, where we need to login into a Application using the Edge browser, after logging we need to make few update and complete the Transaction.

The Web Application that we are using is having some issue so we need to clear the cache ,previous session history & cookies on regular time intervals. When we were working with IE we have a found an easy way to clear them using the Bat File, but that Bat file is not working for Edge.

I have added the bat file command for IE, is there any command same like that for Edge also.

> <RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 4351>

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Thanks in Advance,
Harsha

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear Microsoft Edge browser cache programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32229072/how-to-clear-microsoft-edge-browser-cache-programmatically)

Comment: i have tried but didn't work

Comment: Define "didn't work" please?  Did it error?  Did it do something unexpected?  Did it do nothing, or seem to do nothing? How did you implement the suggestion in the linked answer?

Comment: i have tried that above mentioned Link to clear the cache of Edge, it was a getting an error as Access Denied and was not able to clear any of the data. I have tried keeping them in a Bat and depending the Machine Username i have started that Bat file.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps to do so.

Go to the **setting** page of the browser and search for "**Clearing** **browsing** **data** **on** **close**" and then enable the required options. This setting will clear all the info mentioned on every close of the browser.

Helpful screenshot
[image]

Comment: Please see [answer]. It is better to create answers which target the future audience of visitors to StackOverflow than to only provide information in interactive exchange with OP. Especially for a four month old question.