# Clear Edge Chromium Cache via script on Windows

Tags: microsoft-edge, clear-cache

in history we have provided a script to delete IE cache to users and ask them to run it after updates etc. Now we are switching to Edge and we would like to provide the same script for Edge.

There is the same question but quite old: [Is there any way to clear the cache, cookies & History for Edge Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70590172/is-there-any-way-to-clear-the-cache-cookies-history-for-edge-browser). The solution there is not working anymore and in any case I would not prefer to blindly delete directories. Is there no other solution to safely clear the cache by a single click?

Till now we used for IE:

```
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8 
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 16
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I try to research but at the moment there is no official script available to clear the MS Edge cache.

I would suggest you follow the steps below.

1. Browse to `edge://settings/clearBrowserData` in the Edge browser.
2. Click on the **Choose what to clear** option for Clear browsing data now.
3. Checked the option **Cached images and files**.

[image]

4. Click the **Clear now** button.